# Rails 5, can't use request in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Want to use `request.host_with_port` in controller, but not effect.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
 domain = request.host_with_port
  ...
```

Got error:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `request' for SomeController:Class
...
```

Comment: I guess you need to do it in specific action instead of trying to use it in the context of controller class, which isn't gonna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Request Object](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object)

`request` is for any action of controller, not just only for controller

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
     domain = request.host_with_port  #"localhost:3000"
     url =  request.url #http://localhost:3000/somes/action_name/:id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action you can get host as:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @host_and_port = request.host_with_port
  end
end
```

and to show in home/index.html.erb file with:

```
<%= @host_and_port %>
```

Here is a link to simple rails project on github: 
https://github.com/nezirz/host_controller

You can simply copy project to your pc with: `git clone git@github.com:nezirz/host_controller.git`

and start it after running `bundle install` and `rails s` inside cloned project directory

Comment: Sorry but `request.host_with_port` returns only domain name with port number, it does't return url, url is absolute path

Comment: you can call it as you want this is only a sample